# Failed to run dexer - New install, sample app ("Movies")

Tags: android, appcelerator

I've been searching  around and haven't been able to resolve this issue. I am simply trying to run the sample "Movies" app using the android emulator. This is a fresh Appcelerator, android sdk install on Windows 7.

Here is the error output:

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  Error: Unable to access jarfile null
2016-01-27T21:36:29.189Z | TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
2016-01-27T21:36:29.190Z | ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Andrew\.appcelerator\install\5.1.0\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\plugins\run.js:92:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
2016-01-27T21:36:29.191Z | TRACE  | Sending exit signal to titanium process:  7032
```

**Troubleshooting:**

- Ensure latest SDK installed via android.bat (build tools 23.0.2)
- Configure file locations for zipalign, aapt, aidl, and dx
- Run `aapc ti config android.dx.maxMemory 512M`
- Edit tiapp.xml to this `android:targetSdkVersion="23"`

Here is the Environment Check output:

```
/  Node.js
  √  node               installed (v0.12.7)
  √  npm                installed (v2.11.3)

Titanium CLI
  *  cli                new version v5.0.6 available (currently v5.0.5)

Titanium CLI Dependencies
  √  async              up-to-date (v1.4.2)
  √  colors             up-to-date (v1.1.2)
  √  fields             up-to-date (v0.1.24)
  √  humanize           up-to-date (v0.0.9)
  √  longjohn           up-to-date (v0.2.9)
  √  moment             up-to-date (v2.10.6)
  √  node-appc          up-to-date (v0.2.31)
  √  request            up-to-date (v2.62.0)
  √  semver             up-to-date (v5.0.3)
  √  sprintf            up-to-date (v0.1.5)
  √  temp               up-to-date (v0.8.3)
  √  winston            up-to-date (v1.0.2)
  ×  wrench             missing

Titanium SDK
  √  latest sdk         installed (v5.1.2.GA)
  √  selected sdk       up-to-date (v5.1.2.GA)

Android Environment
  √  sdk                installed (C:\android-sdk-win)
  !  tools              untested version 24.4.1; may or may not work
  √  platform tools     installed (v23.1)
  ×  build tools        unsupported version 21.1.2
  √  adb                installed C:\android-sdk-win\platform-tools\adb.exe
  √  android            installed C:\android-sdk-win\tools\android.bat
  √  emulator           installed C:\android-sdk-win\tools\emulator.exe
  √  mksdcard           installed C:\android-sdk-win\tools\mksdcard.exe
  √  zipalign           installed C:\android-sdk-win\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe
  √  aapt               installed C:\android-sdk-win\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe
  √  aidl               installed C:\android-sdk-win\build-tools\23.0.2\aidl.exe
  √  targets            installed (4 found)
  √  avds               installed (1 found)
  √  ndk                installed (undefined)
  √  ndk-build          installed (undefined)

Java Development Kit
  √  jdk                installed (v1.7.0)
  √  java               installed C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe
  √  javac              installed C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javac.exe
  √  keytool            installed C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\keytool.exe
  √  jarsigner          installed C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\jarsigner.exe

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
  √  compatible         
  !  installed          not found; install HAXM to use Android x86 emulator

Network
  √  online             
  -  no proxy server configured 
  ×  https://www.google.com (HTTP status: 404) is unreachable 
  √  Java-based connection test 

Directory Permissions
  √  home directory     
  √  titanium config directory 
  √  titanium sdk install directory 
  √  temp directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this sample just now and although I did not run into the dexer issue I did ran into other issues because of some out of date things in `tiapp.xml`.

I've a [PR](https://github.com/appcelerator/movies/pull/16) ready. Could you try [my fork](https://github.com/fokkezb/movies/) to see if that might resolve your issue as well?